# PHP get name <td name="x"> with post

Tags: php

Are we able to get the value of the name inside the `<td>`?

Code

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td name='read_recordid'>VALUE</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Using post to get the value

```
if ($_POST['read_recordid']) {
//do something
```

}

Comment: Submitting a form only submits certain fields (namely input, select, textarea and button). Table data cells are not submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 <input type="hidden" name="read_recordid" value=""/>
```

or
Use id in

```
 <td id="id_name"> </td>
```

acess this id using Javascript and post to php code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var x=  document.getElementById("id_name"').value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. We have to use input, select and etc.
Might be you are finding something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="read_recordid" value="VALUE"/>
```

Comment: You can use either input, select, textarea or button.